# Self made ATMega32U4 board first programming

Tags: usb, bootloader, arduino-pro-micro, arduinoisp

I'm stepping into Arduino world and decided to build a small board to implement a gamepad. Prior designing the board I tested my firmware on a *Arduino Pro Micro USB* so I decided to make something similar. My board use an **ATMEGA32U4-AU** instead  **ATMEGA32U4-MU** because it's simpler to solder. Connecting the board to my PC I noticed a new device named *ATmega32U4* appear between Windows devices this sounds like the board is working.
Now the problem is how to program it with the correct bootloader (?) and make it a *real* **Arduino** board.
I found some spurious articles about how to make it but I have not a clean idea. Someone can help me?
I can share everything you need to focus on the board.

UPDATE ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Before installing Arduino bootloader I tried programming a sample firmware on the board trough Atmel FLIP (successfully). After that I never been able to program the board again (neither trough FLIP or other means)

I connected my board to Arduino ISP and since Windows seems unable to find the correct driver I had to install it manually, after that I tried to install the bootloader trough **Install bootloader** option of Arduino IDE (selecting Arduino ISP as programmer) but I had no success:
This's the log:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\tux\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : arduinoisp
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: bus-0:\\.\libusb0-0001--0x2341-0x0049
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : Arduino ISP Programmer
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

Error during bootloader writing.
```

---

I can clearly see that my firmware is not running when I start the booloader process (probably because it reset the board).
From the log it seems that everything is going correctly until:
*programmer operation not supported*

What does it means? Is the programmer unable to program such chip? How can I fix this?
If I reset my board prior trying to burn again a new firmware over it will it work or I just have to put a brand new micro on it?

Best regards,
 Mike

Comment: Sounds like you're in DFU programming mode. There's an app for that.

Comment: You mean this: https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/flip#additional-summary ?

Comment: Looks like it. I never use it, so don't know for sure, but it certainly rings a bell.

Comment: I don't think it can be used to replace a bootloader probably I can use it to program flash with a Arduino hex.

Comment: You could use a different Arduino with the ArduinoAsISP sketch, and burn the bootloader (and fuses) using the ISP pins on the ATMega32u4

Comment: I see ... should I use the install bootloader function in ArduinoIDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong MISO connection given by a bugged ATMega32U4 footprint.